Is it true that $D A P D^T = A D P D^T$ if $P$ is symmetrical, positive definite and $D$ is diagonal?
I know in general, matrix multiplication is not commutative, but would it be true in this special case?
$D A P D^T = A D P D^T$  where $A, D, P$ are all $n by n$ matrix. But $P$ is symmetrical and positive definite matrix and $D$ is diagonal
The context of my problem is that I have a covariance matrix $P$. I want to "scale" the standard deviation inside the matrix. i.e if $P_{ij} = \rho_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j $ I want to make it $\rho_{ij} d_i d_j \sigma_i \sigma_j $ where $d_i$ is the entries on the diagonal matrix $D$.
I am wondering if I "scale" my matrix before the product, is it equivalent of scaling the matrix after the product?

did you try small examples, like 2x2 and 3x3?

No, this is incorrect. Consider the following matrices
$$D = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}, \quad A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad P = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
$D$ is indeed diagonal, and $P$ is indeed symmetric positive-definite since it is symmetric and has eigenvalues $1$ and $3$ (which are both strictly positive).
Then, you can verify that
$$DAPD^T = \begin{pmatrix}12 & 18 \\ 6 & 18\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}14 & 24 \\ 6 & 18\end{pmatrix} = ADPD^T.$$
More intuitively, if you consider the more restrictive case where $D$ is invertible (i.e. it has no zero on its diagonal), then what you are asking is whether $DAPD^T = ADPD^T \iff DA = AD$. However, you have that
$$(DA)_{ij} = \sum_k D_{ik} A_{kj} = D_{ii} A_{ij},$$
$$(AD)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} D_{kj} = A_{ij} D_{jj} = D_{jj} A_{ij},$$
which are clearly not equal in general.
